# How to block ip range in htaccess using specific RewriteCond

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have created proxy and I have got spamming attack on my links.
I know their IPs but I'm not able to block them accessing my website. My code:

```
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from 64.233.172.0/24
Deny from 66.249.83.0/24
Deny from 66.102.8.0/24
Deny from 173.252.81.0/24
Deny from 173.252.100.0/24
Deny from 173.252.102.0/24
Deny from 173.252.113.0/24
Deny from 173.252.73.0/24
Deny from 173.252.75.0/24
Deny from 173.252.79.0/24
Deny from 69.171.228.120
Deny from 69.171.230.117
Deny from 69.171.235.117
Deny from 173.252.107.115
Deny from 173.252.105.117
Deny from 173.252.122.117
Deny from 173.252.114.118
Deny from 173.252.75.119
Deny from 173.252.103.5
Deny from 173.252.88.91

Allow from all

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(script\.php)
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ proxy.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I can't remove these script and proxy files they have to work this way. Please tell me how fix this?

This is my system configuration.

```
Apache 2.2.29
DirectAdmin 1.48.0
Exim 4.84
MySQL 5.5.9
Named 9.7.3     
ProFTPd 1.3.5
sshd
dovecot 2.2.15
Php 5.3.29
```

Answer (score 3):

This depends on which version of Apache you're using.

If you're using 2.2, the following should work:

```bsh
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Deny from 64.233.172
Deny from 66.249.83
# ... etc ...
```

If you're on 2.4, then you should use this instead:

```bsh
Require all granted
Require not ip 64.233.172
Require not ip 66.249.83
# ... etc ...
```

If none of those work for you, then you can use `mod_rewrite` instead:

```bsh
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^64\.233\.172 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^66\.249\.83 [OR]
# ... etc ...
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

#### Update

Based on your comment, please use the below code instead:

```bsh
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^64\.233\.172\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^66\.249\.83\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^66\.102\.8\.
# ... etc (do the same above for each IP address/range and leave [OR] out on the last one) ...
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(dmca\.html)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ proxy.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

You simply had it in the wrong order. You first need to set the base, then disallow certain IP addresses, and *only then* do your other rewrites.

Comment: i have tried like this
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^65\.49\.2\.183 [OR]

RewriteCond $1 !^(dmca\.html)
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ proxy.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^ - [F,L] 
but it didn't work even none of above is working

Comment: ok using your updated code blocks all access, means it blocks all ips no one can access it anymore am using this code..
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^65\.49\.2\.183 [OR]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
RewriteCond $1 !^(dmca\.html)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ proxy.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: Perhaps take the `[OR]` away. When you have multiple IP addresses to match, use `[OR]` for all of them excluding the last one. I will update my answer.

Comment: i did, and i have tried everything, every other domains using different files and structure but none of the codes are working i guess its because of my server, am using Linux Debian 6.. what to do? should i post this in serverfault?

Comment: I think you should, yes. The code I've provided should work just fine - perhaps something else is interfering with it.

Answer (score 0):

You juste have to begin allowing all. You can put the whole thing in a limit tag and replace the range in the form A.B.C.D/24 by A.B.C.

```
<Limit GET POST>
  Order Allow,Deny
  Allow from all
  Deny from 64.233.172.
  Deny from 66.249.83.
  Deny from 66.102.8.
  Deny from 173.252.81.
  Deny from 173.252.100.
  Deny from 173.252.102.
  Deny from 173.252.113.0
  Deny from 173.252.73.
  Deny from 173.252.75.
  Deny from 173.252.79.
  Deny from 69.171.228.120
  Deny from 69.171.230.117
  Deny from 69.171.235.117
  Deny from 173.252.107.115
  Deny from 173.252.105.117
  Deny from 173.252.122.117
  Deny from 173.252.114.118
  Deny from 173.252.75.119
  Deny from 173.252.103.5
  Deny from 173.252.88.91
</Limit>
```

Comment: nope, it didn't work. i have tried like this

Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
Deny from 65.49.2.183

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(script\.php)
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ proxy.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]

but its still accessing my website
i guess the issue with my RewriteCond, it won't let this code work,

Comment: yes rewrite rule working, but this blocking ip code is not working..
even i have tried simply this code..

order allow,deny
allow from all
deny from 65.49.2.183 
but still not working..

Comment: this code is working fine..
    RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(dmca\.html)
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ proxy.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]

but this code is not working..

order allow,deny
allow from all
deny from 65.49.2.183

Comment: Yes, I understood but I modified my answer. If it sill don't work, what is your version of Apache ? Do you have access to the vhost ?

Comment: ok still not working like this, 
<Limit GET POST>
order allow,deny
allow from all
deny from 65.49.2.183
</Limit>

am using this, Apache 2.2.29 - Php 5.3.29.. and yes i have access to ssh

Comment: You can use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` for get the client IP. So you can make a table and check if the IP is in. For the IP ranges, you can use someting like that : https://gist.github.com/tott/7684443